# Can't figure out what is wrong with my functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to attach the stye.css so I can see the changes in my wordpress theme but I'm seeing no CSS on my site. I can't figure out what the error is here.

```
<?php

function learningWordPress_resources() {

  wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'learningWordPress_resources');
```

Comment: yeah still I am not seeing changes  to my site. I have a styles.css functions.php

Comment: index.php header.php and footer.php

Comment: no CSS is going through with the slight format change to functions.php

Comment: it's driving me crazy

Comment: This isn't enough information for us to help you. There is so much more involved in debugging this than seeing where its enqueued. 1. Where is your style.css file? 2. Is the CSS valid? 3. Is anything showing in your page source for the CSS? 4. Are you calling wp_head() in your pages? 5. Have you cleared your cache? 6. You need to change your handle from "style" whether it fixes this issue or not. 7. You didn't mention any "*slight change to functions.php*", so what was it and what worked before? 8. What do you mean by "*index.php header.php and footer.php*"?

Comment: are you developing a child theme? If not then simply name the file style.css, you don't even need a functions.php file for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

first where is the path of css

```
<?php

function learningWordPress_resources() {

  /*wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri() );*/

 // get the directory of your theme location and add the path of css
  wp_enqueue_style('style',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css');

}

//add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'learningWordPress_resources');
   /*
     * replace wp_enqueue_style with wp_enqueue_script
  */
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','learningWordPress_resources');
```

another solution add file of style in header.php file

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For proper versioning based on the file’s last modified time, you can use something similar to:

```
wp_enqueue_style('main-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/css/style.css'), false);
```

When the style.css file is updated on the server, WP will append the appropriate timestamp.

Note: You shouldn’t ever use time() as the 4th parameter or append it to the file, as this will break caching in almost all cases.